# Comparing Dates in SQLite

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I'm currently doing a small project in python and SQLite and I have a csv that has been imported into a database with values under table name : Members.

Each member has a "Date Joined" field in the format m/dd/yy. Some example formats are below:

**I cant change the values in the csv because when I turn this assignment in they're going to use a document with the same format as below**

### Date Joined

5/1/98
6/4/97
7/1/99
8/1/99
8/3/99
11/20/99
2/2/00
1/2/99
2/3/99

One of the questions Im asked is:

to retrieve all member information that have joined after 1999-07-01 (yyyy-mm-dd) and are from VA (can ignore the VA part)

My query to do this something like this started off as

```
SELECT * FROM Members WHERE "Date Joined" >= "1999-07-01" AND "State"="VA";
```

But my problem is that Im having trouble converting the date (Im guessing its stored as a string in the database) so it can be compared with "1999-07-01".

Comment: Your data is bad because you are storing dates in a weird format which is missing even the full year.  If you had the full year, month, and day, you could just substring off these pieces and compare this way.

Comment: Im doing this project as an interview process for a company, and they gave me the csv files with the data. They're going to use the same csv files on their end when I turn it in, so I cant really "change" the csv files on my end to fit what I want to do. Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough.  Here's the problem I see: How do you phrase later than 1999 given the current data?  If you had the full year, you could do `2000 > 1999`, but `00` is not greater than `99`.

Comment: Exactly what Im facing. The example data I provided above only included 2/2/00 as a date. But there are more dates past 1999-07-01, but within the same year. For example 8/1/99, 8/3/99, 11/20/99 (formats in the db).

Comment: I think you will have to make the assumption that `00` always mean `2000` and not the year `1900`.  Then you are really looking for anything _less_ than `99`.

Comment: What is the earliest year in your data set?

Comment: Less than 99 meaning an example date of 1998-05-01 will be returned as well but that isn't ahead of 1999-07-01. The earliest year in my dataset is 1996.

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: Im using version 3.12.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE CAST(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(join_date, INSTR(join_date, '/') + 1), INSTR(SUBSTR(join_date, INSTR(join_date, '/') + 1), '/') + 1) AS INTEGER) <= 16 OR
      (
          CAST(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(join_date, INSTR(join_date, '/') + 1), INSTR(SUBSTR(join_date, INSTR(join_date, '/') + 1), '/') + 1) AS INTEGER) >= 99 AND
          CAST(SUBSTR(join_date, 1, INSTR(join_date, '/') - 1) AS INTEGER) >= 7
      )
```

**Explanation:**

Apologies for such an ugly query, but then again the date data you are working with is also very ugly.  The logic of the query is that is will select all records where the year is `16` or less, *or* if the year be `99` or greater *and* the month be `7` or greater.

The trick here is to carefully use SQLite's string manipulation functions to extract the pieces we want.  To extract the month, use:

```
SUBSTR(join_date, 1, INSTR(join_date, '/') - 1)
```

This will extract everything from the date column up to, but not including, the first forward slash.  To extract the day and year is a bit more work, because `INSTR` picks up the first matching character.  In this case, we can substring the date to remove everything up and including the first forward slash.  So the day and year can be extracted using:

```
SUBSTR(sub, 1, INSRT(sub, '/') - 1)      -- day
SUBSTR(sub, INSTR(sub, '/') + 1)         -- year
```

where `sub` is obtained as `SUBSTR(join_date, INSTR(join_date, '/') + 1)`.

Comment: Im assuming join_date is the column "Date Joined" in my table and not '1999-07-01' (the value that they gave me).

Im using a sqlite manager plugin for firefox that lets me view my tables/data and run queries before I write them in python.  so I will try the query and let you know the results!

Comment: @SaiSrinivasan You assume correctly.  Your date column name had a space, which I didn't want to deal with.  I will work with you to get this query running if possible.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much for your help! For future viewers could you please explain just the logic that you did. Its my first time with sqlite and For future reference I know that Ill be facing a problem like this (im sure many have faced this as well).